# Helper method returning different objects

Tags: c#

I am trying to put more DRY principles into practice and running into a limitation of knowledge. I have written a deserialization routine that I was thinking to use for different objects.

Well it worked great for one object but when I moved it into a helper and went to reuse the deserialization code for another object...well of course it was returning the wrong type...but how would I go about returning different types...overloads (not very DRY?)...perhaps returning a generic object then casting..but then how would my deserialization line work?

Object 1 is ABCD

Object 2 is WXYZ

Helper method is:

```
internal static List<ABCD> DeserializeConfig()
{
  .....snip....
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ABCD>), xRoot);

  //how would this line above work..pass in the object type like below

  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(_passedObject), xRoot);        
}
```

Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the method generic

```
internal static List<T> DeserializeConfig<T>() where T : ISerializable
{
  .....snip....
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), xRoot);

}
```

The above assumes custom serialization where you control how the process is done, exactly how, which fields etc by implementing the `ISerializable` interface. This provides you with a compiler time check. You could also simply use basic serialization and remember to declare your types with the [`Serializable`] attribute in conjunction with [`NonSerializable`] where appropriate - [see docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx)

Comment: I was just typing a comment for further explanation...the objects ABCD and WXYZ are actually third party and thus they are not decorated so the where T check condition has to be dropped...but that isn't your fault. Your way is more thorough and better practice.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)?  Seems like this would be a great place for them.

Your method signature would change to something like 
`internal static List<T> DeserializeConfig<T>()`
where T is the type of the object you want to deserialize?

Calling it, would look like
`var obj = DeserializeConfig<int>();`

Comment: thank you for including the call as well as the link so I can read about generics.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a generic method, something like this:

```
internal static T DeserializeConfig<T>()
{
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), xRoot);

  // ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Marius Generics are indeed the perfect fit.